# Spring Controller "redirect"

Tags: java, javascript, spring, spring-mvc

I'm been search for a solution for this problem for a while and didn't found any!!

To explain the problem I will give and example:

Let's imagine that I have a search page X with results (x1....x10) and a form to give feedback. This form will call a link for a controller (java spring controller) defined as '/feedback.html'. After the submit the feedback, the controller should return again to X with the same results. And here is the problem, how can I do this? because this feedback controller can go to X or to any other page depending where the form is!

In summary: How can I do the javascript history(-1) in the controller (java spring controller)??

Thanks

Comment: How do you get to the search page? with a Get request or a post? i.e. does the search string appear in the url?

Comment: By Get, but what I'm really trying to find is a way to do the history(-1) but in the controller.. (or by getting the headers the resubmit again... I don't know...I don't even know if this is possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you access the search page like this:

```
http://domain.com/search/query
```

or

```
http://domain.com/search?query=text
```

Then you can just pass this ulr along with the feedback form (by adding a hidden input with its value the URL)

```
<% request.setAttribute("redirectURL",
       request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri"));%>
<form:hidden path="redirectURL" value="${redirectURL}"/>
```

And then in the controller simply access the redirectURL property and redirect to the search page with the same query showing the same results.

Comment: That is what I thought to do, but the problem starts when the feedback can be in mutiple pages. I also tried  redirect to request.getHeader("Referer") but if the Referer page has some parameters (for search the query, or for a product page a product Id) I will not get that!!

Comment: I've changed the value of the hidden field, this should put the current url in the value

Comment: it will pass the value of the url of the current page, whatever this page is

Answer (score 1):

The "redirect" Spring capabilities is usually used within a [PRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern. Given your title and your use case, I'll assume you're trying to get redirected to the search page **or** another page after submitting your form (form action seems to be '/feedback.html').

So basically you have your feedback controller which should have a @RequestMapping annotated method like `@RequestMapping(value = "/feedback.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)`. From there and within this method, you can **redirect** the request anywhere you want by returning a String matching an existing mapping in you Spring app (for example, if you want to redirect to the search page, given your search page is mapped with `@RequestMapping(value = "/search.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)`, simply return `"redirect:/search.html"`.
Note that the whole "search page" logic will have to be re-run (the redirect issuing a new GET request) so if you don't want that to happen, you will indeed have to store the search results in session (not sure what sense does that make... but it's possible).
EDIT : If your URL mapping permits it, you can also redirect the request to the search page with search parameters included, something like : `"redirect:/search.html?myParam=10"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, in the search controller, you can **store X in session** and at the end of your feedback controler send a redirect to an URL that call the search controller (same methode or another one) that load the search result page using the X held in session.

You can also pass the X parameter with hiden field (if you dont want to use session).